# acceleration and potential energy due to conservative force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

how can we find acceleration due to a conservative force as a function of time when potential energy due to the conservative force is given as function of position(e.g. U(x)=x^2)

Comment: I think you need a time dependent potential to do the trick. (not exactly sure what you mean though)

Answer (score 2):

The force $F$ is minus the potential energy gradient $\frac{dU}{dx}$ for a conservative field.

$F =-\dfrac {dU}{dx}$

So if you know the mass you can use Newton's second law to find the acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

For a conservative field, the force $F$ can be calculated from the potential energy gradient $dU/dx$ 
$$
F = -\frac{dU}{dx} = -2x
$$
where $U(x) = x^2$ in your example. 
If the mass, $m$, is known, Newton's second law gives
$$
\ddot{x} = \frac{F}{m} = -\frac{2}{m} x 
$$
which is the differential equation for an undamped oscillator. This linear differential equation can easily be solved for $x(t)$:
$$
x(t) = a\cos(\omega t-\phi)
$$
where
\begin{eqnarray*}
a &=& \sqrt{x_0^2+(\dot{x}_0/\omega)^2} \\
\omega &=& \sqrt{2/m} \\
\phi &=& \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\dot{x}_0}{\omega x_0}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}
$x_0$ and $\dot{x}_0$ are the initial conditions, $x_0=x(t_0)$ and $\dot{x}_0=\dot{x}(t_0)$.

Comment: can u provide the solution for x(t)?

Comment: @kishi, the solution is given in the edit.